# How to change the color of the back ground to something the user inputs in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, background

I am trying to make my website so the user can input a color using a color selector, and then it changes the background color to that. This is what I have so far:

```js
function color_change() {
alert("I will make it the color you have choosen.")
var back = document.getElementById("color")
var new_color = document.getElementById("change").value
// What goes here?
}
```

```css
#color {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<HTML>

<div id = "color">
Change the Color
<br>
<input id = "change" type = "Color">
<button onclick="color_change()">Make it this color!</button>
</div>
</HTML>
```

I tried that but all it does is come up with an error. Does anyone know how to make it work? I want it to have the user input a color by clicking the box. When they click the box, a Color Picker opens.  Then, when they click the Make it this Color! button it will set the background of the div to the color they put in.

Comment: as long as you're using `alert()` you can might as well use `prompt()` to get a string variable from the user.

Comment: back.style.backgroundColor = new_color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the background colour of the `color` div element to the newly selected colour. You have correctly managed to retrieve the colour value from the colour input element and stored it in the `new_color` variable.

You can apply CSS styling options to an element via the `style` object. This exposes the [Stylesheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Stylesheet) and the [CSSStylesheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStylesheet) interfaces for you to manipulate. It can both get and set styles. In your case, you would like to set the background colour of an element. So you have to get the element with javascript which you have already done and then access the `style` object followed by the `backgroundColor` property which you can then set equal to the colour value of the colour input element:

```
document.querySelector("#color").style.backgroundColor = "{any css colour value}"
```

Below is adjusted snippet utilising this.

```js
function color_change() {
alert("I will make it the color you have choosen.")
var back = document.getElementById("color")
var new_color = document.getElementById("change").value
// Apply background color to div#color element
back.style.backgroundColor = new_color;
}
```

```css
#color {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="color">
  Change the Color
  <br>
  <input id="change" type="color">
  <button onclick="color_change()">Make it this color!</button>
</div>
```

You can read more about the `style` object and what it can do [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style).